# How can I integrate speech recognition with my camera app?

Tags: android, camera, speech-recognition, voice

I am trying to integrate speech recognition to my camera app, more specifically I want my camera to open up and you click a button "Listen" and it listens for the word "snap" and then it takes a picture.  I have a button on the app already, it is just adding the voice portion to it. How do you get it to check for specfic words?

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html
It shows how to add Voice Recognition to your app.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html
This package is useful for a reference too.

Answer (score 0):

This shows a complete usage of TTS and Speech Recognition

https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-

Also you need the following:

A simple way to match is to use this loop:

```
protected void receiveWhatWasHeard(List<String> heard,
        )
{
    WordDictionary command = new WordDictionary("Add");
    for (String said : heard)
    {
        if (command.isIn(said.split("\\s")))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "heard add");
        }
    }
}
```

and this class:

```
public class WordDictionary
{
    private Set<String> words;

    public WordDictionary(String... wordsIn)
    {
        this(Arrays.asList(wordsIn));
    }

    public WordDictionary(List<String> wordsIn)
    {
        words = new LinkedHashSet<String>(wordsIn);
    }

    public Set<String> getWords()
    {
        return words;
    }

    public boolean isIn(String word)
    {
        return words.contains(word);
    }

    public boolean isIn(String [] wordsIn)
    {
        boolean wordIn = false;
        for (String word : wordsIn)
        {
            if (isIn(word))
            {
                wordIn = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return wordIn;
    }

}
```

And your activity needs this:

```
@Override
    protected void
            onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                List<String> heard =
                        data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < heard.size(); i++)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, i + ": " + heard.get(i));
                }
                receiveWhatWasHeard(heard);
            } else
            {
//fail
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: i tried to import the app you had inside and I got errors mind giving me help?

Answer (score 0):

To actually take the photo once you get the signal that the user has said 'Snap' you have to implement a replacement for the Camera app. You can look at the Camera preview sample app (in API Demos / graphics) to see how to show the preview image. And the Camera class overview has detailed information on how to actually capture the image.